# How to get UNIQUE data based on a derived data, without modifying the original data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Form linked to a spreadsheet. The responses are filtered to separate sheets based on category. In the filter, the submission times from the Google Form entries are converted to date (clock time is not included). The filter is wrapped around UNIQUE() so if someone submits 10 of the same link in 1 day, only 1 link will appear for that day, but it can appear again on another day if submitted again (once per day).

The separate sheets are the "review" sheets, and the data from those sheets are compiled to another sheet with array {} to have all 5 sheets combined, and then there is a different spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE() to display the data from that last sheet.

Each array is sorted with newest date at top, and last row at top. But I do not find a way to sort the entire range to show newest (last rows) at the top no matter what sheet it is from. I could do it by filtering the orginal timestamp with clock time, but then I would get multiple duplicates per day. I can't completely ignore duplicates either. Any tips for me? >.<

Example:

| Links1_Submitted | Links1_Link | Links2_Submitted | Links2_Link | Links3_Submitted | Links3_Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/26/2022 12:00:00 | Links1_Link1 | 9/26/2022 12:05:00 | Links2_Link1 | 9/26/2022 12:10:00 | Links3_Link1 |
| 9/26/2022 12:45:00 | Links1_Link2 | 9/26/2022 12:15:00 | Links2_Link2 | 9/26/2022 12:20:00 | Links3_Link2 |
| 9/26/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 | 9/26/2022 12:35:00 | Links2_Link3 | 9/26/2022 12:25:00 | Links3_Link3 |
|  |  | 9/26/2022 12:50:00 | Links2_Link4 | 9/26/2022 12:30:00 | Links3_Link4 |
|  |  |  |  | 9/26/2022 12:40:00 | Links3_Link5 |
|  |  |  |  | 9/26/2022 12:41:00 | Links3_Link5 |

Links1
`=UNIQUE({ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(A2:A4))), B2:B4})`

| Status | Submitted | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links1_Link1 |
| Status2 | 9/26/2022 | Links1_Link2 |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links1_Link3 |

Links2
`=UNIQUE({ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(C2:C5))), D2:D5})`

| Status | Submitted | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links2_Link1 |
| Status2 | 9/26/2022 | Links2_Link2 |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links2_Link3 |
| Status2 | 9/26/2022 | Links2_Link4 |

Links3
`=UNIQUE({ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(E2:E7))), F2:F7})`

| Status | Submitted | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links3_Link1 |
| Status2 | 9/26/2022 | Links3_Link2 |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links3_Link3 |
| Status2 | 9/26/2022 | Links3_Link4 |
| Status1 | 9/26/2022 | Links3_Link5 |

`=SORT({SORT({A11:C}, ROW(A11:C), FALSE); SORT({E11:G}, ROW(E11:G), FALSE); SORT({I11:K}, ROW(I11:K), FALSE)}, 2, FALSE)`

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9uzZsaMc8eT00i3BvLlTM_1xPSIQg4dF7nGgUSC-eE/edit?usp=sharing) is the same as above, just in a spreadsheet if that is easier

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @player0 thanks, it already has clock in original sheet (Public), but to make sure i do not get more than one duplicate link per day in the review sheets (Discord, Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, YouTube), I convert to date and omit clock

Comment: player0, @TheMaser, thanks for letting me know, I updated my question with spreadsheet links, image and formula snippet, please let me know if I did something wrong. Considering how much data is tied together via different sheets, i found it easier just copying the original spreadsheet, deleting sensitive sheets and sharing here, email sharing does not bother me. for future posts, I will read more on the Tables docs TheMaster mentioned and use that instead for simpler data, thanks

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Start from  scratch.  Create a simple spreadsheet and add one row and one column and see if the issue can be explained, if not add one more row and so on. Don't start from what you have and start cutting down. Starting from scratch is step 1 in creating [mre]

Comment: Gotcha @TheMaster, I updated the spreadsheet - is it better now?

Comment: I don't visit spreadsheets. If you have a [mre], post it preferably as a table or  alternatively a screenshot. The code should be minimal too.  Your formula takes half the question.

Comment: My bad @TheMaster, revised, I hope that is better

Comment: If you remove the timedata from date, how will the formula know which is newer?

Comment: @TheMaster I can't have timedata if I want unique links per date, so I converted - now it sorts based on newest date in each array, with bottom rows at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue seems to `UNIQUE`, where you want

- all the unique links
- exactly once per day

To do this, you're mutating the data to remove time data from timestamps, irrecoverably damaging the original data. To preserve timedata and `UNIQUE`, use `SORTN` instead:

#### [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

##### Input:

| Links1_Submitted | Links1_Link |
| --- | --- |
| 9/26/2022 12:00:00 | Links1_Link1 |
| 9/26/2022 12:45:00 | Links1_Link2 |
| 9/26/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |
| 9/26/2022 13:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |
| 9/27/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |
| 9/26/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |

##### Output:

| Links1_Submitted | Links1_Link |
| --- | --- |
| 9/26/2022 12:00:00 | Links1_Link1 |
| 9/26/2022 12:45:00 | Links1_Link2 |
| 9/26/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |
| 9/27/2022 12:55:00 | Links1_Link3 |

##### Formula:

```
=SORTN(A2:B8,2^99,2,2,1,DATEVALUE(A2:A8),1)
```

This sorts by `DATEVALUE`(a virtual column), but it's thrown away and the original data is preserved. It also removes duplicates in the data, based on the virtual `DATEVALUE` sort column.

Comment: I checked the docs but did not find what the value after ^ could mean, is it number of rows down that will be included? @TheMaster

Comment: @hofebido `^` is power. 2 to the power 99. We just want unlimited number of rows.  Alternatively just remove it  and insert `ROWS(A2:B8)` as `n`

Comment: Ahhhhh, got it!

Comment: I forgot to include filter in the minimal example, not sure if you want me to create a new post or something - just wondering if "SORTN(FILTER(A2:B8, X2:X = "Ca1"),2^99,2,2,1,DATEVALUE(FILTER(A2:A8, X2:X = "Ca1")),1)" works well enough or can it be optimized better?

Comment: @hofebido As always a new question. But on preliminary look, doesn't look so bad. If it works well, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Noted, much appreciated